# What does *= mean in a .pro file?

Tags: qt, qmake, qt-quick

I'm trying to build qtdemo on Windows and I've almost done it, but there is a problem with qtquick examples. I think it begins in qtdemo.pro file, in this part:

```
contains(QT_CONFIG, quick1) {
    QT += quick1
} else {
    DEFINES *= QT_NO_DECLARATIVE
}
```

It always set QT_NO_DECLARATIVE, so the program throws an error and does not run the example. I was searching what does it mean '*=' operator but I couldn't find it anywhere. Does someone know? They always said about += and -= but *= is not mentioned at all...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html):

> The *= operator adds a value to the list of values in a variable, but
>   only if it is not already present. This prevents values from being
>   included many times in a variable.

Comment: thank you. I was searching it yesterday for some time. I don't know why I did't find it in docs. Thanks :)

Comment: I haven't checked the v5.0 docs, but as of v4.8 the `qmake` docs are poorly laid out compared to the API documentation.  It's a shame because `qmake` is actually pretty powerful.

Comment: It doesn't matter, because I'm building right now Qt 4.8 because 5.0 doesn't supprot QtQuick2.0 in designer and I'm an absolute beginner in Qt so 4.8 maybe will be more usefull. I was using OpenCV so I'm used to its docs. Here in Qt it's difficult to me sometimes to find anything but I hope I'll get some experience.